# BIO tagging software

Tags: machine-learning, active-learning

I would like to label character data with BIO tags as part of an active learning process on unlabelled data. I am assuming there are open source GUI tools available which I can use to make this easier - i.e. present the string to be labeled and some way of tagging characters from a predefined set of tags (and probably allow new tags to be added).

I have not been able to find anything though - ideally cross-platform (Linux and macOS at a minimum). It could be a cloud service or AWS product but I'd prefer something which is locally installed.

Does anyone know of such a thing? Even something as simple as search term would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prodigy](https://explosion.ai/software#prodigy) is a tool for data annotation, I think it shines in NLP tasks.

I've also heard about [Amazon mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/), I know it can be used for annotation, but it's more general purpose.

Comment: Prodigy looks nice  - the examples are for annotation of words, do you know if it works for characters as well? I assume so but it's not clear from the first glance

Comment: I don't really know, but it doesn't look like it https://prodi.gy/docs/api-interfaces

Comment: It looks like it can, the live demo includes a "named entity (character based)" example. It's in Chinese (I guess) but you can apply a tag to 1 or more characters unlike the "named entity" mode which always extends the selection to include full words.

Comment: great, explosion is building amazing software, I hope you can make use of it

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, without however the active learning support that prodigy offers, is [doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano). It's open-source (free), easy to install and supports various applications, apart from NER (BIO tagging), also classification and translation.